# Enabling REST API over HTTPS in Azure Data Lake Gen 1

Tags: azure-data-lake

How to enable REST API over HTTPS in Azure Data Lake Gen 1?

Would like know about limitation of Azure Data Lake Gen1.

Comment: what exactly you want to do? Acess https using u-sql? code behind?

Comment: @JorgeRibeiro can you access https from code behind ?!?!?!

Comment: no, that is not possible...